# Calling HTTP command from MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, http

I had to migrate a Production SQL server from SQL 2008 to SQL 2012. The below piece of code was working fine with 2008. For some reason. it complains

> "'HTTP' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file."

Can someone please let me know what is going on ?

```
DECLARE @cmdstr VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @URL varchar(8000)
SET @URL = '"My_URL"'

CREATE TABLE #cmd_result (OUTPUT VARCHAR(8000))
EXEC master..xp_sprintf @cmdstr OUTPUT, 'HTTP /s %s ' ,@url
INSERT #cmd_result
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmdstr

PRINT @cmdstr

SELECT * FROM #cmd_result WHERE len(rtrim(output)) > 1
DROP TABLE #cmd_result
```

Comment: Where is this code from and how is it running? The error "not recognized as an internal or external commannd..." is the Windows command-line telling you HTTP isn't a program to run, which is true. Are you trying to run this SQL into the MS-SQL2012 command line utility? There must be a problem with your escaping somewhere.

Comment: This code is running from a SQL Job. This worked fine with 2008.

Comment: was it a different server? sounds like the http.exe or http.bat does not exists or was moved.

Answer (score 0):

you could run

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'dir http*'
```

and see if your http is showing up. chances are it is not or it needs to be added to the PATH environmental variable in order to access it from anywhere.

Comment: output
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 7C38-885A
NULL
 Directory of C:\Windows\system32
NULL
06/02/2012  06:34 AM            21,271 http.mib
07/25/2012  07:05 PM            39,936 httpapi.dll
11/01/2012  09:18 PM           107,520 httpprxm.dll
11/01/2012  09:18 PM            17,920 httpprxp.dll
               4 File(s)        186,647 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  349,650,989,056 bytes free
NULL

(12 row(s) affected)

Comment: when I print the command it outputs  HTTP /s "My_URL"  and error on SQL 2012 is  'HTTP' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. but worked perfectly fine in SQL 2008

Comment: i would search your server for http.* and either change the job to use the full path in the cmd, move it to where the cmdshell can run it, or update the PATH local variable to include http's path